# Nesting Routes | Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested

E.g.:

```
User: localhost:3000/users/1
Message: localsthost:3000/messages/1
```

Every `Message` has a `user_id`, so i'm trying to Nest the `Messages` like so:

Message 1 from User 1:

```
localhost:3000/users/1/messages/1
```

How can i nest this? I read [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but couldn't understand fully.

I nested the resources:

Routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '',
                     :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :sign_up => 'register' }

  # User Profiles
  get 'u/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

  # Gits
  resources :users do
    resources :messages
  end
```

Now the routes look like this:

```
new_user_message   GET    /users/:user_id/messages/new(.:format)      messages#new
edit_user_messaget GET    /users/:user_id/messages/:id/edit(.:format) messages#edit
user_message       GET    /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)      messages#show
```

Updated my New Message link:

```
<%= link_to "New Message", new_user_message_path%>
```

But i'm getting the Error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"messages", :action=>"new", :id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:user_id]
```

Comment: You practically linked to [the answer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). If you have a specific problem, be sure to include details about what you're trying, expecting, and actually getting in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available in the link that you posted. Search for this title: `2.7 Nested Resources` and learn more. Anyway here is the answer.

```
resources :users do
  resources :messages,only: [:show]
end
```

Also remember not to nest it too deep. More than 1 level of nesting is not great.

---

After the new update to the question. Try this:

```
new_user_message_path(current_user.id)
```

This will work if you are using devise or something that has current_user defined as the current user or if you have some other object like `@user` having the required users information. Then use something like

```
new_user_message_path(@user.id)
```

Basically the problem is you are not mentioning the user id.

Comment: i don't know what i am missing. undefined local variable or method `new_messages_path' neither 'new_user_messages_path'

Comment: Would you mind joining me on chat ? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48527/nesting-resources-rails

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by not providing the expected argument to `new_user_message_path`:

```
<%= link_to 'Create User', new_user_message_path(@user) %>
```

The correct path to create a new message under a user is `/users/:user_id/messages/new`. In order for Rails to construct it, you need to tell it what `:user_id` should be. ActiveRecord objects know how to serialize into a routing-friendly key, so you can just pass in an instance of `User`, rather than specifying `user.id` explicitly.